# Segfault when calling strtok() in loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

this keeps segfaulting and I don't know why... I know you should avoid pointers with strtok, so I'm using a literal... Anyone have any ideas?

```
int getParameters(char input[], char *cmdArgs[]){
  char* cmd;
  int i = 0;
  cmd = strtok(input, " ");
  while( cmd != NULL)
  {
    cmdArgs[i] = cmd;
    cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Took another out... was from a commented implementation I tried. Also added the declaration of cmd... also was removed because of the commented implementation

EDIT 2:

I removed the literal's in favor of pointers... my new implementation is below. It only segfaults when it enters the loop.

```
int getParameters(char *input, char *cmdArgs[]){
  char *cmd;
  int i = 0;
  cmd = strtok(input, " ");
  while( cmd != NULL)
  {
    cmdArgs[i] = cmd;
    cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `strtok()` with a string literal. The function writes to the string it is passed, which you cannot do to a string literal.

Comment: *"I know you should avoid pointers with strtok"* who told you that?

Comment: I don't see the difference between the first block of code and the one under "EDIT 2:".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the specification for strtok.
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );

Where is your *another* pointer pointing? And what type it is?

Comment: I just fixed it; left over from a commented implementation that I deleted for this post

Answer (score 0):

The `*cmdArgs[]`is a fixed size double * pointer. If you are growing it dynamically you will have to call `malloc` for each read cmdArg.

So your segfault is coming from the fact that you are probably writing outside the allocation space of cmdArgs, that is i might exceed the width of cmdArgs

Also what is the type declaration of cmd?

Comment: I pass in a pointer to a large sized array (~100) and so it shouldn't be segfaulting there...

Comment: Is input a string literal in your testing?